# Future Publication date for Salesforce Lightning Knowledge Articles

Tags: lightning-knowledge

I am working on Salesforce Lightning Knowledge. Salesforce out of the box functionality allows users to schedule publishing of article for future date. Howeever this date is not visible on UI or stored in any field of Knowledge objects.

Does anyone know how to get the Future Publication date of knowledge article in Apex?

Answer (score -1):

Currently, there is no way you will know on UI about the future publication date. You will have to build a custom solution using apex for that.
You can use the functions to publish the article and then you can save the date in custom field.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_knowledge_kbManagement.htm

Let me know if you need help with that.

Vishal

Comment: I've downvoted because this doesn't answer the question. The question (ostensibly) isn't about getting this information in the UI (which OP seems to already know isn't possible) but rather if it's possible in Apex.

Comment: I have added the statement which will say it can be done using apex. And when we say we have to build a custom solution that involves apex.